# is it prime - warning match case unused, return true instead of false

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I am trying to make a function in OCaml that says if a number `a` is a prime or not.

Here is the function:

```
let isprime a b = 
  match b with 
   a -> true
  |_ -> if a mod b = 0 then false else isprime (a)(b+1);;
```

When I run : `isprime (4)(2);;` it is saying me `true`, but I don't understand why, because in this case `4 mod 2 = 0`, and hence it should return `false` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an identifier as a pattern, you will bind the value you match on to that identifier. With

```
match b with
| a -> true
```

Instead of comparing `b` to `a`, you're creating a new local variable `a` and assigning it the value of `b`. Which will always succeed, hence the warning about the `_` branch being unused.

I would recommend just using `if/else` instead:

```
let rec isprime a b = 
  if a = b then
    true
  else if a mod b = 0 then
    false
  else
    isprime a (b+1)
```

Edit: Alternatively you could do

```
let rec isprime a b = 
  match () with
  | _ when a = b -> true
  | _ when a mod b = 0 -> false
  | _ -> isprime a (b+1)
```

But since this doesn't do any actual pattern matching, the `if/else` communicates what you're doing better.

Note: You're also missing the `rec` keyword, which I've added above.

Comment: Thank you, so I can't solve th problem using match with ? In this case if I have a function : f a b, it means I can't use match b with and compare b to a using this syntax ?

Comment: @JIJOJJH you can, with `match b with | n when n = a -> ...`

Comment: You can, but you wouldn't do any actual pattern matching in it. `if/else` communicates what you're doing much better.

Comment: Ok, always thought that if/else was exactly the same as match with, and that match with was more use just because it's easier to read...

Comment: **Pattern**-matching detects **patterns** in a data structure. Here, you're only considering values, so pattern-matching isn't the right tool.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you read [the pattern documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html). In a nutshell, patterns have to be constants, so that they can be efficiently optimised by the OCaml compiler. If you want to evaluate an actual predicate and not only constructor matching, you have to resort to the when clause.

Another alternative to the if/else proposed by @glennsl, which IMHO always looks odd in a functional language, you could match the actual result of the comparison:

```
match (a mod b = 0),(a=b) with
  _,true -> true
  true,_ -> false
  |_ -> isprime a (succ b)
```